# Which control posted back my page? (ASP.NET Page)

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

1 -I wonder that how to get which control posted back the page and is there any way to convert

```
Request["__EVENTVALIDATION"]
```

value string to understandable string.

2- in which order components will be bind and how do they get their value from viewstate?

Thank 4 all  your helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On webforms ASP.NET stores the control that initiated the postback in a hidden field called "__EVENTTARGET" except for Button controls.
More information about that can be found [here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-determine-which-Control-caused-PostBack-on-ASP-NET-page.aspx) and [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx).